# Bubble sort, but sorting only even placed numbers ascending and leaving odd placed elements in c

Tags: c, sorting

my problem is to print even placed numbers ascending using bubble sort, so for example {4, 1, 2, 1} after sorting should be {2, 1, 4, 1}. I have code for bubble sort

```
for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        {
            d=0;
        for (j=0; j<size-1-i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])   
            {
                temp = array[j+1];    
                array[j+1] = array[j]; 
                array[j] = temp;
                d++;
            }
        }
        if(d==0)
        break;
}
```

I ofc tried to change values in [] and 'i' but  it gave me strange numbers. Size is size of array.

```
for (i=0; i<size-1; i+=2)
        {
            d=0;
        for (j=0; j<size-1-i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])   
            {
                temp = array[j+1];    
                array[j+1] = array[j]; 
                array[j] = temp;
                d++;
            }
        }
        if(d==0)
        break;
}
```

this is the best try i had but it gave 1 2 1 4 so i was trying to change j but it didnt give results.

Comment: Did you step through in a debugger to see if it did what you expected?

Comment: *"I ofc tried to change values in [] and 'i'"* That's all you need to do, so show us that code.

Comment: first i changed i to i+=2 and i left it but it gave me 1 2 1 4 and i didn tknow why so i tried to do combine with j value but after that i got zeros in array.

Comment: you want to sort only even ou you wan to just print them ?

Comment: sort only even placed numbers so foem array 4 1 2 1 i want to have array 2 1 4 1

Answer (score -1):

Just think to your algorithm stepping by 2 ;

- The size condition in for loop should be `size - 2` to avoid out of bounds RW
- Step is 2 so `i+=2`
- Compare the current number with the next even so `if (array[j] > array[j+2])`

.

```
 for (i=0; i<size-2; i+=2)
    {
            d=0;
        for (j=0; j<size-2-i; j+=2)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+2])   
            {
                temp = array[j+2];    
                array[j+2] = array[j]; 
                array[j] = temp;
                d++;
            }
        }
        if(d==0)
          break
```

Comment: thx i didnt do -2 thing, it doesnt work when u have odd number of elements but i will do second if and check if size is odd or even.